# Android Studio: not a statement error

Tags: java, android

i'm getting this error (not a statement) for this:

```
 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
 boolean 200 = jsonResponse.getBoolean("200");

 if (200) {
```

When i change 200 with succes it works but not with 200?
Can someone help pls.

Comment: Java identifiers can't start with a digit. Call is `is200` or something like that.

Comment: It seems the tag name is 'succes' and not 200? Check your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use `200` as an identifier for a variable. According to the [JLS §3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

You can't use `200` as an identifier (it is interpreted as an `int` literal).

Rename your variable to `is200` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Java variable name cannot begin with a number

Answer (score 1):

change your variable name, first read the java variable declaration guideline, that help you to declare and how to use variable...
use this link
http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-variable-naming-rules/